# Simpy resource queue and count allocated at the same time

Tags: python, simpy

Hi I am trying to visualize the queue and count of a resource but I have trouble when adding a timenout for after working hours/weekends.

I tried to place a timemout until the correct unix timestamp but
either both, the count is at max capacity and queue stays up or both are empty. (I quadruple checked the timestamps if they are correc)

**Logic:**
But given my logic a queue of packages is still there and waiting for processing even if the resource is not getting used.

**Question:**
How/Where can I place a timeout to have the items still be in the resource queue but the resources(count) not being used in order to simulate a stop of work at some stations for after working hours.

**what I tried:**
here is what/where I tried to place the  (if working_hours == False:)

Resources of the warehouse are of type = simpy.PriorityResource

```
##2.5 Robot empties bin at port
    yield env.process(warehouse.robot_empties_or_fills_bin_at_port(bin,warehouse.robot_receive_bin_from_port_time_empty,False))
    #Robot end

#delay,  working_hours = calculate_timeout_delay_with_working_hours(warehouse, env.now,bin,9)
#if working_hours == False:
#    yield env.timeout(delay)

with warehouse.humans_pickers.request(priority=False) as human_request ,warehouse.picking_station.request(priority=False) as port_request:
##  2.4 Human picks items from port
    delay,  working_hours = calculate_timeout_delay_with_working_hours(warehouse, env.now,bin,9)
    if working_hours == False:
        yield env.timeout(delay)

    yield human_request & port_request

    # if working_hours == False:
    #     yield env.timeout(delay)

    yield env.process(warehouse.human_pick_items(bin, warehouse.human_pick_items_time,True))
```

visualized are following variables

```
item = (
            env.now,
            warehouse.robot.count,
            warehouse.robot.capacity,
            len(warehouse.robot.queue),
            warehouse.picking_station.count,
            warehouse.picking_station.capacity,
            len(warehouse.picking_station.queue)
        )
```

please view the picking station named port in the chart on the Sundays 2 and 9th of Jan

**Expectation:** I am expecting "port Queue Length" to stay up (and o up due to new orders) on weekends, while "Port Resource count" stayes down as all the humans are at home.

timout before the with
[image]

timeout inside the with before the yield of the resource
[image]